# Syntax to execute some code before initializing member class objects

Tags: c++, comma-operator

Is there a way to execute some code as a precursor to initializing class members? Take the following code as an example:

```
void enableCreationOfAObjects();

class AObject
{
public:
    AObject(int i, int j, int k);
}

class BObject
{
    AObject a;
public:
    BObject():a(enableCreationOfAObjects(), 1, 2, 3){}
}
```

In the above case, I would like the first comma after calling enableCreationOfAObjects() to be treated as the comma operator and the other commas are parameter separation for AObject constructor.

I can understand this as bad coding style and if that is so, please consider this academic as comma operators are not very common in use. Is there any other way to execute code before member initialization when AObject cannot be rewritten?

Comment: Why won't the straightforward `BObject():a((enableCreationOfAObjects(), 1), 2, 3){}` work for you?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? It seems like you want o make sure that specific code runs before anybody instantiates class-A. This could be solved by a creation/factory class that will ensure that your pre-requirements are met before creating an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using the comma operator and additional parentheses:

```cpp
BObject() : a((enableCreationOfAObjects(), 1), 2, 3) {}
```

The first parameter is going to execute `enableCreationOfAObjects()`, and then `1`. However, there is the issue that function arguments are indeterminately sequenced, and `2` or `3` might be evaluated prior to `enableCreationOfAObjects`. For integer literals, this obviously doesn't matter, but it does matter in the general case.

You can solve this by using an empty base class:

```cpp
struct Empty {};

class BObject : Empty
{
    AObject a;
public:
    BObject()
      : Empty((enableCreationOfAObjects(), Empty{}))
      , a(1, 2, 3) {}
};
```

Data members are initialized in the order of declaration, and base class subobjects are initialized before any data members. Everything is well-defined then.

Note that this uses an empty base class because empty base classes don't have a unique address, and therefore this solution has zero-overhead (in terms of memory added to `BObject`). In C++20, a similar solution can be achieved with [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address):

```cpp
class BObject
{
    [[no_unique_address]] Empty pre_initialization =
       (enableCreationOfAObjects(), Empty{});
    AObject a;
public:
    BObject() : a(1, 2, 3) {}
};
```

Comment: Perfect! The comma operator method works too but surely doesn't look like clean/maintainable code. The C++20 [[no_unique_address]] method seems like a clean way that is actually usable.

Comment: This question came to my mind in the context of an embedded system in which ObjectA for me is a serial port. However, to be able to start using the serial port or even successfully configure the ports registers, I first need to enable the clock to the peripheral and my objective was to keep the clock start function call close in context to where the resource is being created.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to throw another option in the mix:

```
BObject():a([] {
    enableCreationOfAObjects();
    return AObject(1,2,3);
}())
```

The extra copy of aobject should be avoided via rvo.

Comment: This too is a clean way so long as AObject has a copy or preferably a move constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't modify AObject.
And you will always use a BObject to wrap the AObject.

```
class AObjectInit
{
    public:
        AObjectInit() {
            enableCreationOfAObjects();
        }
};

class BObject {
    AObjectInit  initA;
    AObject      a;
    ....
};
```

Comment: Would AObjectInit actually consume any space this way within the BObject layout?

Comment: @KishoreJonnalagadda The only way to know is to measure it (and it may differ from debug and optimized, so check both). But compilers can do what is know as "The small object optimization rule" and as long as you don't take its address it does not actually need any space.